# Is the magnitude of the gradient non zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, vectors

Let $f=u+iv$ be a holomorphic function on a domain $\Omega$. Suppose $x_{0}+iy_{0}=z_{0}\in\Omega$ such that $f^{\prime}(z_{0})\neq0$ and $\left\vert  f(z_{0}) \right\vert > 0$. Let $F(x,y)=\left(u(x,y)\right)^{2}+\left(v(x,y)\right)^{2}$. Is
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \nabla F(x_{0},y_{0}) \right\vert> 0?
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \nabla F \right\vert &=\left\vert \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}F\right) \right\vert \\
&=\left\vert \left( 2u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u+2v\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v, 2u\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u+2v\frac{\partial}{\partial y}v\right) \right\vert 
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you compute $\nabla F$?

Comment: I have tired, but it gets messy and i don't see the end goal. I presume I will have to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations at some point. @DanielFischer

Comment: Ignoring the constant factor $2$, we can write that as $$\begin{pmatrix} u_x & v_x \\ u_y & v_y\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} u\\ v \end{pmatrix}.$$ See something?

Comment: Eh, now I feel stupid. Could you tell me that you see? @DanielFischer

Comment: What is $u_x v_y - u_y v_x$?

Comment: It's $|f^{\prime}|^{2}$. @DanielFischer

Comment: Right. So by assumption, it's $> 0$. And it's the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: Right, this i reckoned. Right, so it's invertible, hence the only element in the null space i the zero vector? @DanielFischer

Comment: Bingo. And by assumption, $f(z_0) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $F=f\cdot\overline{f}$. Hence,$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\overline{f}+f\cdot\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial x}.$$Since we have$$\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial x}=\overline{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)},$$we deduce$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=2\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\overline{f}\right).$$Similarly, we have$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=2\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\overline{f}\right).$$At least one of these expressions does not vanish, and so the answer to the question is yes.